# I cant show an arraylist in a jlist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe, jlist

So basically im creating a list with a lot of information that i get from the user, and i need to display that "Estudiante" created on a list asside. So this is what i first tried, but it tells me that setListData is for arrays, so i tried other thing that i found that included the using .toArray(array) but that didnt work too.
Just to clarify what modelo is i copied this first code

```
public class VentanaEstudiante extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private Sistema modelo;
    /**
     * Creates new form VentanaEstudiante
     */
    public VentanaEstudiante(Sistema unSistema) {
        modelo = unSistema;
        this.setSize(400, 280);
        initComponents();
    }
```

```
private void BotonCrearEstudianteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
        Estudiante unEst=new Estudiante(NombreEstudiante.getText(), Integer.parseInt(CedulaEstudiante.getText()),MailEstudiante.getText(), Integer.parseInt(NumeroEstudiante.getText()), Integer.parseInt(SemestreEstudiante.getText()));
        modelo.agregarEstudiante(unEst);
        ListaEstudiantesJ.setListData((modelo.getListaEstudiantes()).toArray());
```

Estudiante has a toString method, and the superclass, also does.

```
public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + "Numero:" + this.getNumero() + "Semestre: " + this.getSemestre();
    }
```

Here you have my lists and i only copied the listaEstudiantes methods because this are the ones im asking right now. This class Sistema, doesnt have any toString methods because i throught that this arraylist didnt needed one.

```
public class Sistema {
    private ArrayList<Estudiante> listaEstudiantes;
    private ArrayList<Docente> listaDocentes;
    private ArrayList<Equipo> listaEquipos;

    public Sistema(){
        listaEstudiantes = new ArrayList<>();
        listaDocentes= new ArrayList<>();
        listaEquipos=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void agregarEstudiante(Estudiante unEstudiante){
        listaEstudiantes.add(unEstudiante);
    }

    public ArrayList<Estudiante> getListaEstudiantes(){
        return listaEstudiantes;
    }
```

I need to use ArrayList in case you have something that may work better, i just need to use them
This whole project has a lot of showing Lists and sometimes i have to even let the user select things from them, something that i also dont know how to do but i dont know if i can ask more than one question here. The list is also going to need to refresh and all of that but i think i can handle that. Thanks

Comment: A [mre] would help immensely including showing how the JList is declared, for example, is it a `JList<Estudiente>` and if you are using any list models directly. But regardless, if all else fails, you could use a for loop to loop through the ArrayList, adding items to the JList's model.

Comment: ListaEstudiantesJ is the name of the JList, and the ones that appears on the code that i posted is the only times i ever wrote it.

Comment: *"is the only times i ever wrote it"* Is that supposed to be a justification for not posting an MRE that makes it easier to help? What's easier (for me) is to just ignore people who cannot or won't post an MRE. There are plenty of other people who can, and they need help as much as you do.

Answer (score 0):

`JList.setListData()` has two variants, one expecting an array of elements, the other expecting a vector of elements.

Behind the scenes these two methods create an instance of an anonymous subclass of `AbstractListModel` and pass that instance to `JList.setModel()`.

You can easily implement similar code for any `List` instance:

```
static <E> void setListData(JList<E> jList, List<? extends E> listData) {
    jList.setModel(new AbstractListModel<E>() {
        public int getSize() { return listData.size(); }
        public E getElementAt(int i) { return listData.get(i); }
    });
}
```